# Webmoney merchant laravel result url

Tags: php, laravel, webmoney

Пытаюсь подключить мерчант на свой сайт. Result url выдает ошибку 405. Дело в том что я делаю это через роут и контроллер

```
Route::get('webmoney','Democontroller@webmoney')->name('webmoney);
```

И собственно в конроллере код с гайда по мерчант со своими данными. На настройках мерчант на Result url поставлена ссылка типа **'мой сайт/webmoney'** но при проверке выдает ошибку 405

а если создать файл webmoney.php и на Result url поставить **'мой сайт/webmoney.php'** всё работает. Хотелось бы сделать это с помощью роута и конроллера. Кто сможет помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите в документации какой запрос на сервер отправляет Webmoney Merchant, по моему там POST запрос, а вы в роуте указали GET, замените на метод `post` или укажите `any` чтоб принимать любой тип запроса по этому адресу, но это не безопасно.

Так же для POST нужно отключить проверку CSRF, это делается в `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`:

```
protected $except = [
    'webmoney', //указывается url, а не route name
];
```

Comment: Я и POST и GET использовал, та же ошибка 405 код.

Comment: public function webmoney(Request $post){ код здесь}

Comment: @James ещё CSRF нужно отключить для POST, обновил ответ

Comment: Sorry за тупость но как это сделать чтобы не лезть в middleware

Comment: или просто в форме поставить {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: Форма тут не при чем, это идет запрос от Webmoney, можно вообще отключить CSRF на всём сайте, тогда не надо будет ничего менять в middleware

Comment: Yaroslav Molchan огромное спасибо за помощь, я исключил token с middleware и это сработало.